# webpack dev-server: Avoid proxy errors on HTTP errors returned from proxy target

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy

I have a Vue.js project where I have configured a webpack dev-server to proxy all requests to the UI to my backend server. Here is the relevant part of vue.config.js:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: PATHS.build,
    port: 9000,
    https: false,
    hot: true,
    progress: true,
    inline: true,
    watchContentBase: true,
    proxy: {
        '^/': {
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8089',
            secure: false
        },
    }
},
```

I've noticed that if the HTTP response code from http://127.0.0.1:8089 is anything other than 2xx then the proxy fails with the following error:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/test from localhost:9000 to http://127.0.0.1:8089.
>   See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (HPE_INVALID_CHUNK_SIZE).

This also causes the HTTP response code from the request to localhost:9000 to be 500 for any error and all the information about what went wrong on the server side is lost. This is problematic as I want to be able to extract information from error responses to display to the user.

I know it's possible to do because I had it working on an older Angular project which I think was using Webpack 3 (am now using Webpack 4). I tried copying all the dev-server config from this project but it just doesn't seem to work here!

EDIT: I was wrong. The Proxy error does not occur on every bad response but only for one of the requests which is a multipart file upload. Still unable to reproduce this in a smaller example to put on github though so struggling to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: Create a repo on github which reproduces your issue and the people can checkout it out to see what's wrong.

Comment: You should specify more information. What versions of Webpack/Vue.js you're using? Do you have some webserver processing requests before dev-server, such as apache or nginx? The repo with code would be helpful also.

Comment: @Legends I spent some time today trying to put together a minimal example of it failing. Can't share the original project unfortunately. Infuriatingly I can't recreate the problem so Im going to have to work out what I've done differently!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found the problem, and I apologise, it was a lot more of a specific issue than I originally thought when I wrote the question.

Issue was to do with a request which was proxied to another server using the Spring RestTemplate:

e.g.

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
        throws Exception {
        String baseUrl = serviceProperties.getAddress();
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = createMultipartRequest(file.getBytes());
        return restTemplate.postForEntity(baseUrl + "/api/upload", filterRequest, String.class);
    }
```

The ResponseEntity returning from the rest template proxy contained the header "Connection: close" when the response was anything other than 200 which cause the connection to close and caused this request to fail to return anything which subsequently made the dev-server proxy fail on the UI.

Fixed this by not passing the response headers from the rest template proxy to the response:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
        throws Exception {
        String baseUrl = serviceProperties.getAddress();
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = createMultipartRequest(file.getBytes());
        ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.postForEntity(baseUrl + "/api/upload", filterRequest, String.class);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response.getBody(), response.getStatusCode());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message comes from `node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/util/prepareProxy.js`, which define a onError callback for `node-http-proxy`;

So I did some experiment, make back-end api generate 400 404 500 response, but I didn't got this error.

After I happen to close back-end api, error arise:

`Proxy error: Could not proxy request /hello from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:8081 (ECONNREFUSED).`

I search in [the doc](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#listening-for-proxy-events) and find these:

> The error event is emitted if the request to the target fail. We do not do any error handling of messages passed between client and proxy, and messages passed between proxy and target, so it is recommended that you listen on errors and handle them

**So the `onError` do not handle error code, is called only when request fail** (`500 response` is still treated as a complete request, `connection refuse` is not)

---

Go back to your error message, [HPE_INVALID_CHUNK_SIZE] means bad request to the back-end api. In [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1579), it gives an solution: `add a keep-alive header`:

```
devServer: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:9090/front/static-dev/build/',
    port: 9090,
    proxy: {
        '/**': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8080',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
            headers: {
                   Connection: 'keep-alive'
            }
    },
    open: true
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not resolve my problem. I have done some further investigation and I was wrong it was not every bad request causing this Proxy error but only on one particular request which is a multipart file upload. Still cannot recreate this in a smaller example though.

Comment: @Plog Sure, now the problem is why this multipart request fail with an INVALID_CHUNK_SIZE, I am not familiar with chunk encoding. Does the chrome show this error if you request it immediately without proxy?

Comment: I have finally resolved the issue. It was not related to the proxy configuration at all as it turns out. Was something wrong on my back end. Apologies for the confusion. I will award you the bounty for your efforts.